# how do I IP Block someone who is dosing me php or html

Tags: php, .htaccess, ip

My website http://ppyazi.com is currently getting spammed. I can not block the IP address in cpanel. I am wondering if there is any way to block the IP address with php or the htaccess.

This is the ip:

```
122.106.xxx.xxx
```

Comment: It wouldn't have killed you to research this.

Comment: What are you using?  Apache, nginx, IIS, ...?  Do you have access to the full administration of your site?  Is it on linux or windows?  Must you do it at the "web" level?  So many possibilities, so little details...

Comment: I have tried to research. Nothing worked.

Comment: I am using a web hosting service. I dont have access to admin,

Comment: block IP on iptables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running apache and are on shared hosting (no access to firewall on the server), then I would opt for htaccess. This would go in a file named .htaccess in your web directory:

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from 10.10.10.10
Deny from 20.20.20.20
```

Obviously use the IP addresses you want to block instead of these example ones and use a line for each IP

Comment: I am on a shared hosting. Not apache. Would it still work?

Comment: I am assuming your shared hosting server is running apache which this is for. If it's Nginx it will not.